# Calling a jQuery plugin once for static content and content loaded via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, flexslider

I'm using two jQuery plugins: easytabs and prettyPhoto. I want to use the prettyPhoto plugin for images on (1) a static page and (2) on images which is being loaded via ajax by the easytabs plugin.

Here's what I'm doing right now (notice that this works just fine, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto(); // Calling prettyPhoto for the first time (for images on the static page)

    $('#portfolio-tabs').easytabs();
    $('#portfolio-tabs').bind('easytabs:ajax:complete', function() {
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto(); // Calling this again for it to work on images loaded via ajax
    )
});
```

Comment: What is the performance issue you are facing that necessitates a more efficient approach?

Comment: It's ok it would be better if there's a faster selector for the anchors but only if there's performance issue.

Comment: Actually, I haven't noticed any performance issues. It just feels wrong to instantiate the plugin twice... So my code is ok?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the loaded `easytabs` contents are rendered with in `portfolio-tabs` then change the ajax callback to

```
var tabs = $('#portfolio-tabs').bind('easytabs:ajax:complete', function() {
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']", tabs).prettyPhoto(); // Calling this again for it to work on images loaded via ajax
)
```

Comment: That would only instantiate the prettyPhoto plugin after the easytabs ajax request is complete, right? The thing is that I need prettyPhoto before the ajax request has been triggered as well.

Comment: you need to keep `$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto(); ` before `$('#portfolio-tabs').easytabs();` also